# Get first CSS child of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the first element after the `.wrapper` and set that element to have a `padding:20px`. For example, in this case, i want to have the `<h1>` to have a padding of 20px.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```

---

but in this case, I want the `div` class `description` to have padding of 20px.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="description">Text</div>
</div>
```

how can i do that? I tried `:first-child` but it didnt work. thanks.

Comment: You need `.wrapper > *:first-child`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrapper > :first-child {
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <h2>Other Text</h1>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="description">Text</div>
    <div class="description">Other Text</div>
</div>
```

You can omit `>` if you are certain there will never be any elements nested within the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS using [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) selector.

```
.wrapper > :first-child {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```css
.wrapper > :first-child {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="description">Text</div>
</div>
```

---

Or use [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) methods in jQuery.

```
$('.wrapper').children().first().css('padding','20px')
```

```js
$('.wrapper').children().first().css('padding','20px')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="description">Text</div>
</div>
```

---

Or using [`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) pseudo-class selector.

```
$('.wrapper > *:first-child').css('padding','20px')
```

```js
$('.wrapper > :first-child').css('padding', '20px')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="description">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS:

```css
.wrapper :first-child {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="description">Text</div>
</div>
```